# Sorting NSMutableArray with custom class by date

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have `NSMutableArray` named "allConversations" that contains a custom class "Users".
every user have property "lastMessageDate".

e.x : user.lastMessageDate;

what is the best way to sort the array by date?

I have this code :

```
  NSMutableArray *arrCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:unSortedArr];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastMessageDate" ascending:TRUE];
    [arrCopy sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

but I don't know how to implement it in this situation

Comment: What happens when you you use `lastMessageDate` instead of `createdAt`?

Comment: My mistake, the "createdAt" is the "lastMessageDate". I changed it now

Answer (score 1):

it seems all you are missing is the assignment. This should work for you.

```
arrCopy = [arrCopy sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:YES]]];
```